# prepareForSegue not called when UITableView row selected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I have setup a UITableView using a NSFetchedResultsController that displays a number of prototype UITableViewCells. I have hooked up a push segue from my UITableViewCell to my DetailViewController.

In my TableViewController I have implemented both:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

When I run the application and click on a row in the tableView my application only calls:

```
[TableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]
[TableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]
[TableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]
```

If I delete the segue and rewire it form a UIBarButtonItem to the DetailViewController then the segue is called correctly, can anyone think what I am missing?

## EDIT:

Added:

```
- (IBAction)tester:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SEGTEST" sender:nil];
}
```

and connected it unto a UIButtonBarItem that called "tester" and it works, I just can't get it to fire still when I link from the UITableViewCell to the controller.

Comment: Like my answer below. Why not just link it from ViewController to ViewController and call it in the didSelectCell method?

Comment: I could do I guess, I was more curious as to why it was not firing. The only difference I can see between this and a working version I have is that this version uses Core Data and a UIFetchedResultsController, although I can't see how that should matter.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After a bit of digging I eventually found that the `UITableViewCell` identifier was set incorrectly to "`CELL_ID`" when it should have been "`PLANTCELL_ID`".

Som for anyone else who finds that selecting a `UITableViewCell` in a `UITableView` does not call the associated segue, **check if your cell identifier is set correctly in both the storyboard and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`**.

Answer (score 6):

Rewire your segue from the `ViewController` itself and give it a name.
Then in the `didSelectRow` method call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueName"];
```

and see if it fires.

Comment: It does indeed fire, but how do we pass data to the instantiated scene/view.

Comment: You use the prepareForSegue method.