# Retrieving UITableViewCell Label Values For Passing To Modal Edit View

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I am trying to pass existing attribute values for a managed object, to a modal segue view for editing.  From "editing mode," I'm going from a UITableViewController subclass (BreadRackTableViewController), using a modal segue to a UIViewController subclass (EditBreadRackTableViewController) by means of an embedded UINavigationController.  Normal TableViewCell selection pushes to another UITableViewController subclass, but that's not important for the time being.

I've added properties to my editing view controller header (and @synthesized), to function as getters:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id existingBreadRackDataName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id existingBreadRackDataDetails;
```

What I'm trying to do is populate the edit view's fields with the existing Core Data Entity Attributes, which would have been previously set by the user (in theory).  I can get the data to show up if I pass along a literal string value, but I need to retrieve and pass the existing data.

Here's what I have currently:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"editBreadRackSegue"])
    {
        EditBreadRackTableViewController *ebrtvc = (EditBreadRackTableViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        BreadRackClass *breadRackClass = [[self fetchedResultsController]objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        // [ebrtvc setBreadRackClass:breadRackClass];
        ebrtvc.existingBreadRackDataName = breadRackClass.breadRackDataName;
        ebrtvc.existingBreadRackDataDetails = [breadRackClass valueForKey:@"breadRackDataDetails"];
    }
}
```

These last two lines of code...

```
ebrtvc.existingBreadRackDataName = breadRackClass.breadRackDataName;
ebrtvc.existingBreadRackDataDetails = [breadRackClass valueForKey:@"breadRackDataDetails"];
```

...they both return nil.  If I specify a literal string though, that literal string shows up where it needs to.

All of that said, my question is:

> How do I retrieve the attribute's key value for that selected row (or just the textLabel and detailTextLabels), and assign it to my setter?

**Solution:**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"editBreadRackSegue"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        BreadRackClass *breadRackClass = [[self fetchedResultsController]objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [segue.destinationViewController setExistingBreadRackDataName:[breadRackClass valueForKey:@"breadRackDataName"]];
        [segue.destinationViewController setExistingBreadRackDataDetails:[breadRackClass valueForKey:@"breadRackDataDetails"]];
    }

    // code for other segues here...
}
```

I ended up removing the ebrtv variable, and cleaned up the code a little bit.  What worked though, was using the *indexPathForCell:sender* instead of *indexPathForSelectedRow* when declaring my indexPath for breadRackClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the indexPathForSelectedRow could be a problem.

You can just pass the indexPath from the didSelectRowAtIndexPath to the prepareForSegue , like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"editBreadRackSegue" sender:indexPath];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"editBreadRackSegue"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *clickedIndexPath = (NSIndexPath*)sender;
        if( [clickedIndexPath isKindOfClass:[NSIndexPath class]] ){

            BreadRackClass *breadRackClass = [[self fetchedResultsController]objectAtIndexPath:clickedIndexPath];

            EditBreadRackTableViewController *ebrtvc = (EditBreadRackTableViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
            ebrtvc.existingBreadRackDataName = breadRackClass.breadRackDataName;
            ebrtvc.existingBreadRackDataDetails = [breadRackClass valueForKey:@"breadRackDataDetails"];
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Please forgive me, for my Objective-C knowledge is yet in its infancy, but how do I use that apply the appropriate values to my setters (and without invalidating my other prepareForSegue statements that I've excluded from the code above due to irrelevancy)?

Comment: I put the code in there, as suggested, but the addition of didSelectRowAtIndexPath created some navigation bar corruption.

I have an edit button declared in my viewDidLoad, and the table cell segues differently if it's selected during editing or not.  I was thinking that the didSelectRowAtIndexPath would interfere, and it looks like it does.

The NSLog statements that I have for those two fields (existingBreadRack..etc) are still returning "(null)" though.

Comment: First off:  Thank you for the assistance, and my apologies for not thanking you earlier!  Second:  accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath nets the same navigation bar corruption, however using willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath has no navigation bar corruption (albeit with null values sent).

Comment: I think it has something to do with how the cells are connected to the data. You could check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400429/prepareforsegue-not-called-when-uitableview-row-selected

Comment: I added a few log statements into both the modifications you suggested, as well as my original code:

`NSLog(@"Sent Name: %@",ebrtvc.existingBreadRackDataName);
            NSLog(@"Sent Details: %@",ebrtvc.existingBreadRackDataDetails);`

When I perform the segue while the app is running, it's telling me that the Sent values are also "(null)."  Interestingly enough, when paired with the willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath method:  the NSLogs for the sent portion never gets logged.

Comment: Yea, the data is being saved to the *.sqlite file, but for some reason it isn't being referenced here.  It's like it's creating a new entity, instead of referencing attributes for an existing one.

Comment: I also tried to put this into my prepareForSegue, thinking I could create some reference to just the selected cell's properties rather than the passed Core Data:  `UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[sender indexPathForSelectedRow]];`  But when I tried to test it, with this simple log:  `NSLog(@"Sent Name: %@", cell.textLabel.text);`, the thing threw an error at me:  `[UITableViewCell indexPathForSelectedRow]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

Comment: Ah, hah!  I got it to work!  I wound up with something quite similar to what you had suggested here, too.  So I'll go ahead and mark this (the only answer too) as the correct answer, then update the original question with the finished code implementation.  The performSegueWithIdentifier reference, using the sender as the indexPath is what's working.  I just needed to use it in a different manner.