# table view cell not selectable

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a segue from the table view cell (in a master view controller) to a view controller and gave the segue the name "ShowDetail". In prepareForSegue in the master view controller, I setup this code, however if I touch the table view cell in the master list, nothing happens, not even the first log statement gets triggered. when I right click the table view cell in the master view controller, it shows that there's a segue wired up. [image]

Is there a method that needs to be implemented in the master view controller to make the cell response to a touch? or is there another explanation why this might be happening?

```
-prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"prepare for segue");
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"]){
        NSLog(@"in segue to display edit");

        DisplayEditViewController *devc = (DisplayEditViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        //        devc.delegate = self;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Event *selectedJoke = (Event *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        devc.currentJoke = selectedJoke;
        devc.mood = selectedJoke.mood;
        devc.delegate = self;
        devc.mnemonicField = selectedJoke.mnemonic;
        devc.jokeField = selectedJoke.joke;


    }
```

Update 2

here's a compressed version of the project. As you see, my project lets me add new entries but not display them in the DisplayEditViewController https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10328969/preppyspeech.zip

Update 3

Even when I implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath in the masterviewcontroller, it (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) is not getting called when I click on the cell. See updated project here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10328969/preppyspeech2.zip

Comment: Anything related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400429/prepareforsegue-not-called-when-uitableview-row-selected

Comment: @iphonic no the Cell identifier in mine is "Cell", both in storyboard and in main view controller

Comment: @iphonic I put a link to my project in the update to the OP if you want to look

Comment: Which class has been wired to the table view's delegate?

Comment: Are you calling the [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"ShowDetail" sender: self] in the tableview did select row method!!

Comment: @Nassif I do this ` [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetail" sender:indexPath];` in that method, but didSelectRow is not getting called when I touch the cell...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have seen you Project, there is simple mistake, the `Selection type` for `UITableView` in `MasterViewController` is set to `No Selection`, so `didSelect` method for UITableView doesn't work, change it from image below

[image]

And it works.

Cheers.